# How to differentiate Compact Framework vs Full Framework .NET assemblies

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

Is there any way to differentiate a .NET assembly that is targeted for Compact Framework and runs in Windows CE from another which is not?

I'd say more, is there any difference in the compilation method besides CF lack of methods and classes?

If my assumptions are correct a .NET application targeted to run in Windows CE will always run on desktop Windows, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to tell whether a given assembly was originally built to target the desktop or Compact Framework, you can look at the public key token for the assembly or the assemblies that it references.  From the MSDN article [Write Code Once For Both Mobile And Desktop Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163387.aspx):

> Note that the public key token for the
>   .NET Compact Framework assemblies
>   starts with 9 whereas the desktop
>   equivalents start with B. You can use
>   that information to quickly determine
>   whether what you are deploying or
>   referencing is a desktop or a device
>   framework assembly.

As to whether a desktop assembly can work on CF or vice versa, ctacke addressed that quite well in his answer.  The MSDN article may be worth a look as well, as it provides some examples and strategies for writing code that can be shared effectively between CF and desktop framework.

Answer (score 4):

Differentiate how?  Programatically?  By looking at it in Explorer?  With Reflector?

Assemblies compiled for the CF are "retargetable" and will run under the desktop framework *provided* you don't use anything CE-specific (P/Invoking coredll, using the WindowsMobile assembly, SIP control, etc).

Assemblies compiled for the desktop will not run under the CF under any circumstance.  They must be recompiled.

One major difference in compiled output is that the CF CLR doesn't support all the opcodes the desktop does, so desktop IL may be invalid under the CF.  It's not necessarliy what prevents a full framework assembly from working under the CF, but it's a large part of it.